# Object of class Database could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using this methode to get data from db

```
class Database {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'),Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if (count($params)) {
                foreach ($params as $param) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }

            if ($this->_query->execute()) {
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count   = $this->_query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
        if (count($where) === 3) {
            $operators = array('=','>','<','>=','<=','<>');

            $field      = $where[0];
            $operator   = $where[1];
            $value      = $where[2];

            if (in_array($operator, $operators)) {
                $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE ${field} {$operator} ?";
                if (!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where); 
    }

    public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
    }

    public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
        if (count($fields)) {
            $keys   = array_keys($fields);
            $values = null;
            $x      = 1;

            foreach ($fields as $field) {
                $values .= '?';
                if ($x<count($fields)) {
                    $values .= ', ';
                }
                $x++;
            }

            $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`".implode('`,`', $keys)."`) VALUES({$values})";

            if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
        $set    = '';
        $x      = 1;

        foreach ($fields as $name => $value) {
            $set .= "{$name} = ?";
            if ($x<count($fields)) {
                $set .= ', ';
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

        if (!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function first() {
        return $this->_results[0];
    }

    public function error() {
        return $this->_error;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

[this is what i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O587t.png) **AND**
[this is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFDVF.png)

this is my code ...

```
public function getModule() {
    $epreuve = $this->_db->get('epreuve', array('concour_code', '=', $this->data()->concour_code));
    foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreuve){
        echo "<tr><td>".$epreuve->designation."</td>"
        .$module = $this->_db->get('module', array('epreuve_code', '=', $epreuve->code ));               
        foreach($module->results() as $module){
        echo "<tr><td>".$epreuve->designation."</td>";
        }
        "</tr>";

    }
}
```

but i have this error

**'' Catchable fatal error: Object of class Database could not be converted to string ''**

Comment: How you're doing the database connection ?

Comment: show the entire database class if possible, or at least the functions / methods that you have called above like results()

Comment: i added the full class on topic :)

Comment: i know that i can do that for exemple using this query 

$note = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT ..... FROM ....WHERE ....... ");

but i want to get the result with the methode get()

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be here:

```
echo "<tr><td>".$epreuve->designation."</td>"
    .$module = $this->_db->get('module', array('epreuve_code', '=',
```

Note that you did not close `echo` with semi colon, and there is a dot before `$module`, so PHP is trying to string concat echo string with $module class plus the iteration also inside the concatenation. You cant do that.

Do the following:

```
public function getModule() {
    $epreuve = $this->_db->get('epreuve', array('concour_code', '=', $this->data()->concour_code));

    foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreuve){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$epreuve->designation."</td>";
        $module = $this->_db->get('module', array('epreuve_code', '=', $epreuve->code ));              
        foreach($module->results() as $module){
            echo "<td>".$epreuve->designation."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }

}
```

Suggesiton:

On your code

```
foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreuve){
```

AND

```
foreach($module->results() as $module){
```

You should not use the same variable name of what you are iterating. Try change it to

```
public function getModule() {
    $epreuve = $this->_db->get('epreuve', array('concour_code', '=', $this->data()->concour_code));

    foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreu){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$epreu->designation."</td>";
        $module = $this->_db->get('module', array('epreuve_code', '=', $epreu->code ));              
        foreach($module->results() as $mod){
            echo "<td>".$epreu->designation."</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

NOTE: The HTML table is a bit messy I tried by best to understand it. Change it to your needs.

Comment: thank's it worked ... 

what should i do if i want to add another condition for exemple

$module = $this->_db->get('note_condidat', array('module_code', '=', .$epreu->code.'AND' .$module->condidat_concour_id. '=' $this->data()->ID. ));

Comment: Remember to mark the answer as the right answer. For your question try this https://gist.github.com/falmar/b92b29684c297169f62026c827d66637

Comment: i have this error her 
Fatal error: Call to a member function results() 

Notice : thath the code is 

                    $module = $this->_db->get('note_condidat', array(
                            array('module_code', '=', $epreu->code, 'AND'),
                            array('condidat_concour_id', '=', $this->data()->ID)
                              ));

so i'm trying to get user ID to compare it with the condidat_condour_id

Comment: does condidat_concour_id belong to module_code? where is the user ID? make sure $this->data()->ID return what you want

Comment: it the same like $this->data()->concour_code (to get concour_code from users table) 

just i want to get ID this time ...

Comment: Since you are using the same instance, $this->data() will probably return different data each time you make a query

Comment: Save the ID of the user in local variable then use in $module... array('condidat_concour_id', '=', $user_id)

Comment: it doesn't work :/ 
also if i wompare it to $epreu->id for exmpl 
                    $module = $this->_db->get('note_condidat', array(
                            array('module_code', '=', $epreu->code, 'AND'),
                            array('codidat_concour_id', '=', $epreu->id)
                              ));
i get the same error

Comment: Are you debbuging that the SQL query is well formed and the values you passing are the ones you want in the search?

Comment: this is my table data and the code  [github](https://gist.github.com/falmar/b92b29684c297169f62026c827d66637#gistcomment-1760114)

Comment: check the gist github

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/falmar/b92b29684c297169f62026c827d66637#gistcomment-1760138) same problem :/