# Getting wrong data from database

Tags: php, mysql

**you can check my  [database class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810422/object-of-class-database-could-not-be-converted-to-string/36811031?noredirect=1#comment61198159_36811031)**

when i call this methode

```
    public function getNote() {
            $epreuve = $this->_db->get('module', array('concour_code', '=', $this->data()->concour_code));
            $id = $this->data()->ID;
            foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreu){
                $epreu_code = $epreu->code;

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$epreu->epreuve_code."</td><td>".$epreu->designation."</td>";
                $module = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT note_condidat.note,note_condidat.condidat_concour_id,note_condidat.module_code
                                        FROM note_condidat,
                                        WHERE note_condidat.condidat_concour_id = {$id} AND note_condidat.module_code = {$epreu_code} "); 

                foreach($module->results() as $mod){
                    echo "<td>".$mod->note."</td>";
                }

                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```

**Note : 
$this->data()->ID
return user ID**

i'm getting wrong data !! it take note from the module table not from note table

[image: Tables]
[image: Results table]

Comment: Where does that 8 come from/ what does it relate to in the tables? There is nothing here to display anything is wrong but the last picture..

Comment: it came from module table .... [module table](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=422656Ca222pture.png) 
i want to get the note from note table ... when module_code = module.code AND condidat_concour_id = users.ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved :)

```
    public function getNote() {
            $epreuve = $this->_db->get('module', array('concour_code', '=', $this->data()->concour_code));
            $id = $this->data()->ID;
            foreach($epreuve->results() as $epreu){
                $epreu_code = $epreu->code;
                $note = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT condidat_concour.ID,note_condidat.note,note_condidat.condidat_concour_id,note_condidat.module_code,module.code
                                                            FROM note_condidat,condidat_concour,module 
                                                            WHERE note_condidat.condidat_concour_id = '{$id}' AND note_condidat.module_code = '{$epreu_code}' ");
                echo "<tr>";
                echo  "<td>".$epreu->epreuve_code."</td>";
                echo  "<td>".$epreu->designation."</td>";
                echo "<td>";
                print_r($note->first()->note); echo "<b>/".$epreu->note."</b>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo  "<td>".$epreu->coef."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
```