# Drag and Drop using jQuery Save the new order

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i'm using drag and drop to order a list with jquery ....

and i want to save the new order to Database by clicking a button for exemple

this is my methode to get list element

```
     public function test() {
            $choice = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM choix WHERE condidat_concour_id = ".$this->data()->ID." ORDER BY ordre ASC");
            foreach($choice->results() as $choi){   
                $cs_code = $choi->cs_code;
                $cs = Database::getInstance()->query("SELECT code,designation,site
                                                            FROM cs 
                                                            WHERE code = '{$cs_code}' ");
               echo "<li id=".$choi->id.">";
               echo "<span class='handle'><i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v'></i><i class='fa fa-ellipsis-v'></i></span>";
               echo "<span class='text'>".$choi->cs_code."</span>";                      
               echo "</li>";
            }
    }
```

[image: List]

[image: Database]

I'm looking to use this Script to save order

```
function saveOrder() {
var articleorder="";
$("#sortable li").each(function(i) {
    if (articleorder=='')
        articleorder = $(this).attr('id');
    else
        articleorder += "," + $(this).attr('id');
});
        //articleorder now contains a comma separated list of the ID's of the articles in the correct order.
$.post('set_order.php', { order: articleorder })
    .success(function(data) {
        alert('saved');
    })
    .error(function(data) { 
        alert('Error: ' + data); 
    });
```

but i don't know what i should use in set_order.php ??
i'm trying with this code but i didn't get any result !!

```
$i = 1 ;
$orderlist = explode(',', $_POST['ordre']);
foreach ($orderlist as $k=>$order) {
        $sql  = 'UPDATE choix SET ordre = :ordre WHERE id = :id' ;
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':ordre', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->execute();
        $i++ ;
}
```

**you can check my Database classe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36810422/object-of-class-database-could-not-be-converted-to-string/36811031?noredirect=1#comment61198159_36811031)**